# Creating enrollment token gives back wrong QR code

Tags: android, android-management-api

I'm trying to provision a device with QR code method [according to these documentations.](https://developers.google.com/android/management/provision-device#about_qr_codes)

I'm using this [Google collab quickstart guide](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/android-management-api-samples/blob/master/notebooks/quickstart.ipynb) to do so.

Right now, I'm stuck here:

```
enrollment_token = androidmanagement.enterprises().enrollmentTokens().create(
    parent=enterprise_name,
    body={
        "policyName": policy_name,
        "qrCode": "{'android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_COMPONENT_NAME': 'com.tmp.app.admin/.AdminReceiver','android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_SIGNATURE_CHECKSUM': 'MUQ6NEQ6MDQ6NTY6M0E6ODA6Mzg6NEY6NUM6ODI6Qzk6NUY6MkM6QjA6RTk6RDc6QTM6RjI6NDg6NTA6QTQ6RjY6QTA6RjM6MTA6NUM6MzI6NkY6QkU6NUI6M0E6Qzk%3D','android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION':'https://myurl-stuff.com/link_part/my_app.apk','android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_SKIP_ENCRYPTION': false,'android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_WIFI_SSID': 'MY_WIFI_SSID','android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_WIFI_PASSWORD': 'my_wifi_password','android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_WIFI_SECURITY_TYPE': 'WPA'}"
         }
).execute()


json.dumps(enrollment_token, indent=2)
```

Whenever I run this code, the output is the following.

```
{\n  "name": "enterprises/LC00y54m79/enrollmentTokens/UV4yLfxoyWSln7CArwtp7OJQiHH_Gvc76JttPa4-r48",\n  "value": "ZBNWPOWHBQUPNLMBTNRU",\n  "expirationTimestamp": "2023-02-06T12:43:34.634467Z",\n  "policyName": "enterprises/LC00y54m79/policies/policy1",\n  "qrCode": "{\\"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_COMPONENT_NAME\\":\\"com.google.android.apps.work.clouddpc/.receivers.CloudDeviceAdminReceiver\\",\\"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_SIGNATURE_CHECKSUM\\":\\"I5YvS0O5hXY46mb01BlRjq4oJJGs2kuUcHvVkAPEXlg\\",\\"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION\\":\\"https://play.google.com/managed/downloadManagingApp?identifier=setup\\",\\"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_ADMIN_EXTRAS_BUNDLE\\":{\\"com.google.android.apps.work.clouddpc.EXTRA_ENROLLMENT_TOKEN\\":\\"ZBNWPOWHBQUPNLMBTNRU\\"}}"\n}
```

It is the default Google example **and it does not contains my application**, instead, it contains Google's official example app.

What am I doing here wrong?

**EDIT:**

I have syntax error with double quotes.

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

Also tried with starting and ending single quotes like:

```
'{"android.app.extra (...)
```

Also tried with starting and ending with **triple quotes like in Google's previous example like here:**

[image]

But still no luck.

The api either **returns a syntax error or simple doesn't returns with my app/parameters in the qrCode**, instead it replaces to their own example project.

**EDIT 3:**

Tried like this:

[image]

But with no success:

[image]

Comment: The `qrCode` JSON seems to be formatted incorrectly. Try using double quotes for your fields and values.

Comment: @petarov Can you elaborate please? Maybe with an example?

Comment: Sure, just replace the `qrCode` parameter with something like: `"qrCode": '{"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_COMPONENT_NAME": "com.tmp.app.admin/.AdminReceiver" ...etc}'`

Basically, you switch the single quotes with double quotes in your qrCode string.

Comment: @petarov No luck. See my edit please.

Comment: Your JSON starts and ends with double quotes ("). My example in the comment above starts and ends with single quotes ('). Change the quotes and the error will be gone.

Comment: @petarov The error is gone but I still get back google's app instead of mine in the response. Also tried with triple quotes, no luck. Also, see my edits.

Comment: what do you mean by google app? can you show your response here after the error disappeared?

Comment: @rsiason "Google API" I mean Android Managment API, response is the same as I stated below my "Whenever I run this code, the output is the following." sentence of the post. Can't copy it here because it is too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to manage devices :

- Provision a device with your own DPC : Your DPC is installed (referenced by an URL in the QR code). It fetches policies from your servers and applies them as a profile / device owner, without using any Google API (Android only).
- Manage devices using [Google Play EMM API](https://developers.google.com/android/management). It is basically Google's layer on top of the Android API (but often called Android Management API, which is a bit confusing) : Your EMM console send policies to Google's servers. They are applied on the devices by Google's own DPC.

You are trying to mix the two approaches. It is [no longer possible](https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/emm-api/register) :

> Android Enterprise is no longer accepting new registrations for custom device policy controllers (DPC) using the Google Play EMM API.
> All new EMM solutions should now use Android Management API, which comes with its own DPC provided by Google.

The Google DPC is the [com.google.android.apps.work.clouddpc](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.work.clouddpc) you are seeing in the generated QR code.

If you want to use you own DPC, you need to use the json containing the `android.app.extra.PROVISIONING*` keys directly, without wrapping it in a Google token.

The content looks fine except the SSID has to be quoted, and the signature hash should not be percent encoded :

```
{
    "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_COMPONENT_NAME": "com.tmp.app.admin/.AdminReceiver",
    "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION": "https://myurl-stuff.com/link_part/my_app.apk",
    "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_SIGNATURE_CHECKSUM": "MUQ6NEQ6MDQ6NTY6M0E6ODA6Mzg6NEY6NUM6ODI6Qzk6NUY6MkM6QjA6RTk6RDc6QTM6RjI6NDg6NTA6QTQ6RjY6QTA6RjM6MTA6NUM6MzI6NkY6QkU6NUI6M0E6Qzk=",
    "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_SKIP_ENCRYPTION": false,
    "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_WIFI_PASSWORD": "my_wifi_password",
    "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_WIFI_SECURITY_TYPE": "WPA",
    "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_WIFI_SSID": "\"MY_WIFI_SSID\""
}
```

You just have to generate a QR code containing this content (with any generator), and scan it with the device.

Unfortunately the provisioning process is not forgiving. If something is wrong, the device shows a "Provisionning failed" error message without any clue. You have to triple check everything.

Comment: Same experience. In the response my app is replaced by google's DPC app, and my wifi data is just erased.

Comment: You should not use `androidmanagement.enterprises().enrollmentTokens().create` at all (this Google's API, which require Google's DPC)
Just directly paste the json content in any online QR code generator

Comment: I mean the json containing the `"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_*"` keys, this is what the device expects

Comment: The `androidmanagement.enterprises().enrollmentTokens().create` is which gives me an `enrollmentToken`, you cannot bypass using the API, you cannot provision a device without that token.

Comment: Either you use Google's API (you need a token, you must use Google's DPC, provisioning via NFC, QR code or zero touch) or you handle everything yourself (no token, your DPC, NFC or QRcode, but not zerotouch)

Comment: You are trying to mix Google API + custom DPC. It was possible years ago, but not anymore.
It may still be possible for providers who were already registered when they shut registration down

Comment: And is there a way to make a custom DPC? Whenever I want to provision a device without an enrollment token it doesn't let me pass through after QR code reading, resulting in a faulty provisioning.

Comment: What do you mean "faulty provisoning" ?

Comment: I've just checked my DPC on a Pixel 5, API 33 provisioned with a QR code containing the keys shown in the answer

Comment: Without an enrollmentToken? And you can still control it with policies?

Comment: not Google policies, my custom DPC is device owner and applies custom policies (fetched from my own server).